# Join rows of dataframe into one list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've have dataframe whose rows are list of words .How do I join all those strings into one list?
Below is my dataframe:

```
label          rev

0   0   story man unnatural feelings pig

1   0   airport starts brand new luxury

2   0   film lacked something couldnt 

3   0   sorry everyone know supposed art
```

Expected output:
story man unnatural feelings pig airport starts brand new luxury..

I tried ' '.join(da.rev) , but everytime I execute it, my notebbok crashes and I need to restart it.

Any help will be dearly appreciated .Thank you for your time.

Comment: '  '.join(list(data['rev'])) will do the job i guess

Comment: If you actually want a list, use `df.rev.tolist()`.  If you want to join the strings, use `df.rev.str.cat(sep=', ')`

Comment: @user3483203 tolist() worked well . Thank you

Comment: @iamklaus adding list() to my code worked , missed that. Thank you

Comment: If the rows have comma separated words(list) instead of string , will the approach be the same?